# Webpack compiles successfully, but does not create output file

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to set webpack up (Mostly learning basics about webpack, babel and node.js) and it seems everything goes fine. Webpack says everything is compiled, I get no error messages but there is no output file.

My setup is as such:

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, './'),
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  mode: "development",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

package.json:

```json
{
 "name": "hello-babel",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "description": "A simple Node app built on Express using Babel",
 "main": "server.js",
 "scripts": {
   "build": "webpack",
   "start": "webpack && node server.js"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "express": "^4.16.3",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
   "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
   "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
   "webpack": "^5.0.0",
   "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
   "babel-loader": "^8.1.0"
 },
 "engines": {
   "node": "10.x"
 },
 "license": "MIT",
 "keywords": [
   "node",
   "glitch",
   "express"
 ]
}
```

Comment: Have you created the directory `src/` and the file `src/main.js`?

Comment: How you are running webpack? I've tried your setup and I can see the output file in `public/bundle.js`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroMondéjar - with your proposed edit, you removed one line of the example `const path = require('path');` I am not sure, whether this was intentionally.

Comment: @derM Sorry, it's fixed. Thanks for the report.

Comment: I have src and src/main.js. I can also see that webpack sees all the files in there and all references and compiles them. Just no output shows up.